# How to change access type of inherited type in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider following example:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Table: protected vector<int>
{
public:
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
}
```

All vector's methods are either private or protected, except `begin()` and `end()` which are public.  I can call these two methods from the outside of `Table` class.  However I cannot assign their return values to variables because their type is protected.

```
Table t;
t.begin();
Table::iterator iter = t.begin(); // this will fail.
```

How to make `Table::iterator` public?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use *using declarations* to pick and choose which parts of `std::vector` you want to make public in your class:

```
class Table: protected vector<int>
{
public:
    using std::vector<int>::iterator;
    ....
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
};
```

if you simply want to use `std::vector`'s `begin` and `end` members, you can say

```
using std::vector<int>::begin;
using std::vector<int>::end;
```

Note that this makes both `const` and non-`const` overloads public.